# C/C++ - Pointer passed to function in DLL

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

Lets say i have the following function in my DLL:

```
void TestFunction(int type, void* data)
```

Now that function is called from an application which loads that DLL. The application initializes a structure and sends a pointer to that structure to that function:

```
SampleStruct strc;
TestFunction(DT_SS, &ss);
```

So far so good. Now what troubles me is how to replace the strcc variable in memory with another structure. If i do the following in my dll:

```
SampleStruct dllstrcc;
data = &dllstrcc;
```

***data*** will now point to the new **dllstrcc** structure however when it exists the function and the control returns to the application the **strc** will still point to the first structure. How can i replace the structure of the application with my structure from the dll without assigning each field:

```
data.vara = dllstrcc.vara;
data.varb = dllstrcc.varb;
data.varc = dllstrcc.varc;
```

Comment: First let me note, that it sounds like you are on the way to undefined behavior (by giving away pointers to local data) and point out that constructs like `void*` should be avoided (no pun intended) in C++ (as it is possible most of the time). That said: What about a reference/pointer to the pointer, that will let you replace the pointer on caller site?

Comment: @Nobody In reality it's not a void* but lets say it boils down to it. As for pointers to pointers i am not in control of the application nor the dll function. However the code inside the function is in my control.

Comment: If you are tied down to that interface there is not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The simplest option is to copy the whole struct:

```
void TestFunction(int type, void* data) {
    SampleStruct dllstrcc;
    // fill dllstrcc here...
    SampleStruct *p_ret = data;
    *p_ret = dllstrcc;
}
```

And call it via

```
SampleStruct strcc;
TestFunction(type, &strcc);
```

The benefit is that you don't have to worry about freeing memory, etc.

2. If you really want to replace the structure of the caller (have a new structure), you can allocate a new structure in the DLL.

```
void* TestFunction(int type) {
    SampleStruct* pdllstrcc = new SampleStruct();
    return pdllstrcc;
}
```

(I'll `return` the new structure because it's much easier, but you could pass it out through a parameter if you need to by using `void** data`.)

You can call the function like:

```
SampleStruct *strcc = TestFunction(type);
// do something with the struct
delete strcc;
```

Don't forget to delete the pointer, otherwise you'll leak memory. You should explicitly decide who's responsibility it is to free the memory, the caller's or the DLL's.

Answer (score 0):

you could change the function to

```
void *func(int,void *)
```

and return the new struct - but note that it has to be allocated on the heap with new or malloc, and later freed with free or delete by the caller

btw, doesnt the default assignment operator do what you need?

```
sampleStruct newStruct;
sampleStruct *tmp=(sampleStruct *)data;
*tmp=newStruct;
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you coding in c or in c++?

First: if you want to call the function like this:

```
SampleStruct strc;
TestFunction(DT_SS, &strc);
```

You can't. what would it mean to replace `&strc`? You are trying to replace the address of a structure? That has no meaning. Also in c++ you don't use `void *`, you use `SampleStruct *`

if you want to replace something you have to call it like this:

```
SampleStruct strc;
SampleStruct * pstrc = & strc;
TestFunction(DT_SS, pstrc);
```

now you can replace pstrc with your result, if you write your function like this:

```
void TestFunction(int type, SampleStruct * & data)
```

Notice the `&`, this means you're passing the pointer data as a reference.
Now you can write `data = & dllstrcc;`, and it will modify `pstrc`, because `data` is not a variable, but a reference to `pstrc`. But you may want to learn about memory handling and memory leaks before you try it.